# Splitting the Home dir two different partitions

Tags: directory-structure, desktop, home

I run a Ubuntu desktop environment with two harddisks. 
A small SSD and a large regular disk.

Currently i run a setup where my home drive is located on `/home/name`, but some folders e.g. `Downloads` are linked to a folder on the regular harddrive.

This setup has several issues as it tends to get difficult to maintain and remember which folder belongs to where and so on.

Is there a more simple and elegant way to manage this kind of setup?

Edit: SSD is 128GB

Comment: I didn't really find anything that i was looking for :(. So I created a new project that will fix the issue. The idea is mvln program that reads a file with a list of folders to move to a secondary list and then create a link back. Here is a link: https://github.com/rasmusprentow/mvln

Answer (score 3):

I run a similar setup to the one you're suggesting. 120GB of stupid-fast PCI-E SSD, 4TB of slow, RAIDed, spinning rust. `/` and and `/home` are both on the SSD as is the bulk of my userdir.

I have just symlinked things like `~/Documents/`, `~/Music/`, `~/Photos/` and `~/Videos/` (that's to say, all the big stuff) over to the RAID array. It's not hard to keep track of but I'm guessing that's because 120GB is right at the sweet spot. It's plenty of space for all my installed applications and most of the silly "I won't cry if they're nuked by a SSD fault" files in `~/` aren't that big.

Steam has been the biggest recent challenger to free disk space and that has a built-in method for allowing you to specify alternative install locations. I just move low-played stuff to RAID or delete it.

If you're running 60GB or 30GB... You might want to look for something bigger. It's certainly not impossible (I used to live out of a 60GB SSD with the same RAID) but there isn't a good solution. You either manually map everything (fast performance, annoying) or you dedicate the whole SSD as a cache for the slow drive with something like `bcache` (slower performance, easier).

Comment: You could use `bind` mounts for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

[UnionFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) allows you to transparently overlay two separate filesystems. The caveat is that you can't decide which system to write data to, ad-hoc, but you can have read-only or rarely-changed "archive" data in the same directory as your recent downloads, and e.g. your archives come from one (nearly full) disk, and your downloads go to another (almost empty), and they are visible side-by-side, in the same directory.

Another option is [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management). This one requires a more thorough change - you'll have a hard time implementing it on existing system that didn't use LVM from moment one. Essentially, it separates the "Partition Table" abstraction layer from "Physical device" abstraction layer, introduces another layer of partitioning. An LVM partition can span multiple disks, or even multiple media. Say, you have two 1.5GB disks. With LVM you can create three 1GB partitions on the shared space the two disks form. Or, if you like, you can create a single 3GB partition that covers both disks. You can even later expand that partition by adding another disk.

Thing is, it's better done before installing the system. Migrating an existing system from non-LVM to LVM is somewhat tricky (although if I'm not mistaken, it can co-exist with old "physical" partitions, so you can make your /home an LVM partition spanning one disk and a part of another, while the remainder of the system remains on the remainder of the disk, not subject to LVM.)

Comment: Wouldn't LVM simply have you use the two disks as one larger disk, though? I get the feeling the OP wants to use the SSD for some things and the HDD for others, which seems non-trivial if possible at all using LVM.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: Yes, it lets you use many smaller disks as one large disk, but then you can partition that large disk as you desire - you can control how the logical partitions are distributed over the physical drives at creation time, so you can e.g. make `/` a separate partition that is fully contained within the SSD, and `/home` to span remainder of the SSD and the HDD.

Comment: That doesn't help you if you want some files and directories in your home directory on the HDD and the remainder on the SSD.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: True, for that you're better off using aforementioned UnionFS. Nevertheless, you'll always be compromising between transparency and control - either you control which file goes to which drive (e.g. through softlinks) or you just save it but have no control which drive it goes to.

Answer (score 0):

I have a data disk where I offload things from my home directory in similar situation (encrypted home directory with limited space and slow access).

On the alternative location I have a directory structure, with files only in the end-nodes. 
I made a simple script that recreates the directory structure under `~`, but for the end-nodes, those are linked (`ln -s`). An option to the script shows me a tree view of the directories linked that way (and their parents) and what local files/directories  are there that are not linked and the size (helps decide what to move away).

Important in the setup is a unique directory in the alternative location that only is used for linked (sub)directories. Initially I did not have that and I had to extend the script when top level directories were added.

This helps with maintenance, if you need extra reminders you need to do something like make `ls` into a function, or extend your file manager to smartly display link information.